type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<String>' while fetching data from localstorage?
I have created LocalStorage class for saving data to local storage
The main purpose of this class to store like favourite products, cart Items and thats why I have use T so that the saveData and readData methods can be used with all data types.
But while fetching data from local storage in onInit, it's showing an error.
List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<String>

So how to solve this?
class MyLocalStorage {
  late final GetStorage _storage;
  static MyLocalStorage? _instance;
  MyLocalStorage._internal();

  factory MyLocalStorage.instance() {
    _instance?? = MyLocalStorage._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }

  static Future<void> init(String bucketName) async {
    await GetStorage.init(bucketName);
    _instance = MyLocalStorage._internal();
    _instance!._storage = GetStorage(bucketName);
    print('Bucket Name =' + bucketName);
  }

  Future<void> saveData<T>(String key,T value)async {
    await _storage.write(key, value);
  }

  T? readData<T>(String key) {
    return _storage.read(key);
  }
}

And here is my controller for favourite products:
class FavouriteController extends GetxController {
  static FavouriteController get instance => Get.find();

  final RxList<String> favourite=<String>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    initFavourite();
  }

  void initFavourite() {
    final fromStorage = MyLocalStorage.instance().readData('Favourite');
    if (fromStorage != null) {
      favourite.assignAll(fromStorage);
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveToStorage() async {
    MyLocalStorage.instance().saveData('Favourite', favourite.value);
  }
}


Here favourite is expecting List<dynamic>.It is getting Iterable . You can see difference here.
class FavouriteController extends GetxController {
  static FavouriteController get instance => Get.find();

  final RxList<String> favourite=<String>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    initFavourite();
  }

  void initFavourite()
  {
    final fromStorage=MyLocalStorage.instance().readData('Favourite');
    if(fromStorage!=null)
      {
        favourite.assignAll(fromStorage.toList().cast<String>());        <-- change here
      }
  }
  Future<void> saveToStorage() async{
    MyLocalStorage.instance().saveData('Favourite', favourite.value);

  }
}


Got it..it means i can solve also with for loop inside if like       for(var x in fromStorage)
{
favourite.add(x) as String;
}

HI can u please chek my new question, regarding this...i got strange output its a small program need ur help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78555710/listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-iterablestring-in-flutter
