List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<String> in flutter
I am getting an error if i remove await uploadData() code from main
List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<String>


Thats fine..but according to me this error should come at all the way whther i call uploadData() or not..bcz its type cast error and i have not given any code regarding it inside uploadData method...
I cant understand why error is go
Future<void> uploadData()async
{
   await MyLocalStorage.instance().saveData('Names', ['A','B','C','D']);
}

void main() async
{
  List<String> myNames=[];
  await MyLocalStorage.init('PractiseWork');
  await uploadData();
  final data=await MyLocalStorage.instance().readData('Names');
  if(data!=null)
    {
      myNames.assignAll(data);
      print("My Names ="+myNames.toString());
    }

}


class MyLocalStorage {

  late final GetStorage _storage;
  static MyLocalStorage? _instance;
  MyLocalStorage._internal();

  factory MyLocalStorage.instance() {
    _instance??=MyLocalStorage._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }

  static Future<void> init(String bucketName) async
  {
    await GetStorage.init(bucketName);
    _instance=MyLocalStorage._internal();
    _instance!._storage=GetStorage(bucketName);

  }

  Future<void> saveData<T>(String key,T value)async
  {

    await _storage.write(key, value);

  }

  Future<T?> readData<T>(String key)async
  {

    return await _storage.read(key);
  }
}



error
List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<String>


Does this answer your question? Type inferring doesn't work properly when saving List of objects in Hive box

I did not get the error you mentioned. Can you try with the code below:
void main() async {
    await MyLocalStorage.init('PractiseWork');
    await uploadData();
    final myNames = await MyLocalStorage.instance().readData('Names');
    if (myNames != null) {
      print("My Names =" + myNames.join());
    }
  }

I don't understand why you are assigning,
List<String> myNames=[];

and doing this. Where is this assignAll func coming from.
myNames.assignAll(data);

Also if you want to display array as string. Use join() as in the modified main() func above,
myNames.join()


error not coming..thats my query...it should generate error bcz readData returning List and i am storing response in List..just comment upload data and u will get error..this same erros should come evenif upload data is placed

I don't fully understand but the thing is you can store anything that is why the type is dynamic. When you are reading the data you have to likely provide type to the read function so that it knows what type you have stored.
